# Using VBScript or batch to change Shortcut Icon

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to create a batch file that will toggle a desktop shortcut icon from icon0 to icon1 and back again on second execute.

The Desktop Shortcut points to the batch file in Desktop/toggleicon.BAT, (Batch files is in same directory) but I'm having trouble at the first stage of changing the icon on first execute.

This is my code in the batch file:

```
Const DESKTOP = &H10&
Set objShell = CreateObject(“Shell.Application”)
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(DESKTOP)
Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(“Shortcut.lnk”)
Set objShortcut = objFolderItem.GetLink
objShortcut.SetIconLocation “C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll”, 13
objShortcut.Save
```

I imagine I'm simply googling the wrong thing.

If you know the whole code, awesome. If you can help with the current code to get the icon changing then that's great too, of course I'll mark as solution etc.

Comment: This is vbs not PowerShell or batch

Comment: This is neither Powershell or a batch-file, and it has nothing to do with batch-rename. This is VBScript. I'd suggest that the very first thing you attempt to do is learn the language you're writing code in; it makes it much easier to search for answers to questions when you at least have a vague idea (like the programming language you're using) when searching. In this case, it's probably not working because you're trying to run a VBScript file with a .bat extension, and it's not running at all. VBScript uses a `.vbs` extension.

Comment: @KenWhite is absolutely right the code you have posted is VBScript not Powershell or a Batch File. Having those tags will just confuse both yourself and those who leave answers. To run that code rename the file with a `.vbs` extension and then run it using either `cscript.exe` *(for console usage)* or `wscript.exe` *(for GUI usage)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This a batch code that generate a vbscript to create a shortcut on your desktop with icon that can be changed any time when you call this sub like this way :

```
Call:CreateShortcut "%windir%\system32\calc.exe" "Calculatrice" "Winver.exe,0"
```

or to :

```
Call:CreateShortcut "%windir%\system32\calc.exe" "Calculatrice" "%Windir%\System32\moricons.dll,6"
```

The Whole Batch script to test :

```
@echo off
Title Create a shortcut on your Desktop with icon that can be changed any time by Hackoo
mode con cols=75 lines=3 & color 9B
Call:CreateShortcut "%windir%\system32\calc.exe" "Calculatrice" "Winver.exe,0"
echo(
echo                Hit any key to change the icon shortcut....
pause>nul
Call:CreateShortcut "%windir%\system32\calc.exe" "Calculatrice" "%Windir%\System32\moricons.dll,6"
cls & color 9E
echo(
echo                   The icon shortcut has been changed...
echo                Hit any key to change the icon shortcut....
pause>nul
Call:CreateShortcut "%windir%\system32\calc.exe" "Calculatrice" "%Windir%\System32\SHELL32.dll,13"
cls & color 9D
echo(
echo                   The icon shortcut has been changed...
echo                Hit any key to change the icon shortcut....
pause>nul
Call:CreateShortcut "%windir%\system32\calc.exe" "Calculatrice" "%Windir%\System32\SHELL32.dll,14"
cls & color 9F
echo(
echo                   The icon shortcut has been changed...
pause>nul
Exit /b
::****************************************************************************************************
:CreateShortcut <ApplicationPath> <ShortcutName> <Icon>
(
echo Call Shortcut("%~1","%~2","%~3"^)
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************^)
echo Sub Shortcut(ApplicationPath,Name,Icon^)
echo    Dim objShell,DesktopPath,objShortCut,MyTab
echo    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell"^)
echo    MyTab = Split^(ApplicationPath,"\"^)
echo    If Name = "" Then
echo    Name = MyTab(UBound^(MyTab^)^)
echo    End if
echo    DesktopPath = objShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"^)
echo    Set objShortCut = objShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath ^& "\" ^& Name ^& ".lnk"^)
echo    objShortCut.TargetPath = Dblquote^(ApplicationPath^)
echo    ObjShortCut.IconLocation = Icon
echo    objShortCut.Save
echo End Sub
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
echo ^'Fonction pour ajouter les doubles quotes dans une variable
echo Function DblQuote(Str^)
echo    DblQuote = Chr(34^) ^& Str ^& Chr^(34^)
echo End Function
echo ^'**********************************************************************************************
)> Shortcutme.vbs
Start /wait Shortcutme.vbs
Del Shortcutme.vbs
Exit /b
::****************************************************************************************************
```

Comment: The OP doesn't know the difference between a batch file and VBScript, posting this what do you think's going to happen? I'll tell you, you will confuse the OP still further. They have a simple enough VBScript there all they need to do is run it.

Comment: I do like your script but I just don't think it's relevant to the question the OP is asking and more likely to confuse then help, sorry.

Comment: That is entirely up to you. The problem as I see it is the OP wasn't asking for code they just didn't understand how to run the code they had confusing it with a batch file. Would your VBScript example be much different to the code in the initial question?

Comment: I'm making my first batch files today, and have learnt the difference between .bat (batch file) .vbs (visual basic script) and Powershell. Future readers might benefit from knowing this difference. Luckily that script is pretty straight forward enough for me to understand, and although I would mornally agree with Lankymart, Hackoo has provided a more thorough answer to my whole problem, which was outlined in the question. So Vote +1.

Comment: Do I place this line:       Call:CreateShortcut "%windir%\system32\calc.exe" "Calculatrice" "Winver.exe,0"       in another batch file?

Comment: @AceThanks Yes, but with its function

Comment: By function you mean the .vbs or is each "Call:..." a spereate function that I made add to my .bat file?

Comment: @AceThanks it is better to post in new question and with your modified code !

Comment: I have it now. The function is the Call: piece. Thank you. This answer worked for me. This is indeed a .BAT file answer as originally requested, that makes use of VBScript inside of it. I would suggest that the person who changed the name of the question can now change it back. Thank you all.

Comment: @AceThanks You still not making sense, you can't have a batch file that makes use of VBScript inside it unless you do what Hackoo has done and output to a file using `echo` *(which is a batch command)* to a file then using `cscript.exe` to run it. What you actually posted was VBScript nothing more no batch commands period.

Comment: @AceThanks Wow [reading the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854003/using-vbscript-to-change-shortcut-icon#comment61300103_36858017), you really *"understand"*. You know how batch functions work right? It's so easy to understand but then I'll ask like 10 questions just to be sure.

Comment: @AceThanks Preparing for the next question once you realise you can't get it to work because you just don't understand how it works. That's the problem with just accepting answers that give you code.

Answer (score 2):

Another, simpler way to do the same If your open to using Powershell. Save the following powershell script as MakeShortcut.ps1

Change the filepaths, extension, shortcut name, .ico filepath and name, etc to match your needs.

```
# Create a Shortcut with Windows PowerShell
$SourceFileLocation = "$env:userprofile\FILEPATHTOTARGETPROGRAM.EXTENSION"
$ShortcutLocation = "$env:userprofile\Desktop\SHORTCUTNAME.lnk"
#New-Object : Creates an instance of a Microsoft .NET Framework or COM object.
#-ComObject WScript.Shell: This creates an instance of the COM object that represents the WScript.Shell for invoke CreateShortCut
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutLocation)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $SourceFileLocation
$Shortcut.IconLocation = "$env:userprofile\FILEPATHTO.ico"
#Save the Shortcut to the TargetPath
$Shortcut.Save()
```

In your .bat program, call a function (testshortcut in this instance) to check if the shortcut has been made, and make it if not. Choose a location and name to store the confirmation File as / to.

Use Conditional checks within TestShortcut to Control what the icon is changed to (keep track of the state by storing a value in the ARBITRARYFILEPATH\NAME.txt file that you can check and modify within the function for your conditional checks).

```
:TestShortcut

IF EXIST "ARBITRARYFILEPATH\NAME.txt" GOTO :EOF

Powershell.exe -NoProfile -executionpolicy -Bypass -File FILEPATHTO\CreateShortcut.ps1

ECHO ShortcutInstalled >ARBITRARYFILEPATH\NAME.txt

GOTO :EOF
```

Answer (score -2):

As mentioned in the comments, the code you have there is not a Batch File so creating a `toggleicon.BAT` file will do nothing as those commands will not be interpreted and probably just error.

The code is actually VBScript which can be executed using either of the two Windows Scripting Host programs

1. `cscript.exe` - For executing code using the Windows Console *(command prompt)*
2. `wscript.exe` - For executing code using the Windows GUI

Follow these steps to test the code above

1. Rename the file with a `.vbs` extension, based on your question I'd suggest `toggleicon.vbs`.
2. Then run either of the two commands *(depending on the requirement define above)*

   <sup>From a Console Window *(`cmd.exe`)* or via a batch file;</sup>

   ```
   cscript.exe "toggleicon.vbs"
   ```

   <sup>From the Run command *(<kbd>❖</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)* or via a batch file;</sup>

   ```
   wscript.exe "toggleicon.vbs"
   ```

> **Note:** If not in the correct path make sure to pass the full path not just the filename.

---

#### Update

I just don't understand why you think [that is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36858017/692942), the code you provided was straight up VBScript NOT a batch file and placing that in a file with a `.BAT` extension will just give an error?

This is just nonsense!

> <sup>[Comment by @ace-thanks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36854003/using-vbscript-to-change-shortcut-icon#comment61299686_36858017)</sup>
>   *I'm making my first batch files today, and have learnt the difference between .bat (batch file) .vbs (visual basic script) and Powershell. Future readers might benefit from knowing this difference. Luckily that script is pretty straight forward enough for me to understand, and although I would mornally agree with Lankymart, Hackoo has provided a more thorough answer to my whole problem, which was outlined in the question. So Vote +1.*

If you think you have learnt anything, you are sadly mistaken.

Let's just analyse the original question...

> This is my code in the batch file:
>
> ```
> Const DESKTOP = &H10
> Set objShell = CreateObject(“Shell.Application”)
> Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(DESKTOP)
> Set objFolderItem = objFolder.ParseName(“Shortcut.lnk”)
> Set objShortcut = objFolderItem.GetLink
> objShortcut.SetIconLocation “C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll”, 13
> objShortcut.Save
> ```

If that is your batch file then running that would give you the following error;

> 'objShortcut.Save' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

This is because `objShortcut.Save` is VBScript syntax not Batch Command syntax.

There is a really simple way to get this example to work, just rename the file with a `.VBS` extension as already mentioned and if you *really* need to execute from a batch write one like this;

Batch file called `toggleicon.bat`

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO.
ECHO "Create Shortcut Example"
ECHO.
cscript.exe /nologo "toggleicon.vbs"
```

Just make sure both the batch file and the VBScript file are in the same directory when executed.

Comment: My original code was not a batch file, and 3 comments helped identify that, however with regret offered no batch file solution. In my question I wrote: "_I'm trying to create a batch file..._" and "_The Desktop Shortcut points to the batch file in Desktop/toggleicon.BAT, (Batch files is in same directory) but I'm having trouble at the first stage of changing the icon on first execute. This is my code in the batch file:_" As outlined by the heading that I originally had, and indicated by the description, I was looking for a batch file solution, regardless of what my code looks like.

Comment: @AceThanks if you wanted a batch file solution why post the VBScript it is people like you that make trying to help on SO a chore instead of a privilege.

Comment: I didn't know it was a VBSCript, and this is why I wrote" _I'm making my first batch files today, and have learnt the difference between .bat (batch file) .vbs (visual basic script) and Powershell._ because in posting this, SO users helped me realise it wasn't batch file code.